# Table: expand column to fit width, but keep row height to single line

Tags: html, css

I have a table that fills its container's width. It has three columns. Two columns have a fixed width while the third must expand to fill the remaining width. The width of the table is dynamic.

I can get this to work if a row's height may expand, but I need each row to only have a single line of text. If the text is too long then it must be cut off.

**Code + examples: (https://jsfiddle.net/o044tq53/5/)**

**EDIT:** I rewrote the above description and updated the jsfiddle with an example showing what it should look like.

```css
#wrapper {
  width:200px;
  background:white;
}
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:left;
}
.td_col_two {
  width:100%;
}
.col_one_div {
  width:90px;
  background: red;
}
.col_two_div {
  background: lightblue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.col_three_div {
  width:20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class = "col_one_div">
        Robin
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class = "td_col_two">
      <div class = "col_two_div">
        nowrap does not work for long text.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class = "col_three_div">
        x
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to keep each column at a maximum regardless of it's content? It's not very clear as to what your objective is nor is the description of table. What is it's desired behavior vs. undesired behavior?

Comment: Two columns have fixed width and only the middle one expands to fill the width of the table. I've now clarified this in the question. If you look at the jsfiddle, then the last table should look like the middle table, but with the longer text shortened to fit.

Comment: Have you considered truncating long text and making the ellipsis an anchor to the full text?

Comment: I don't see a way to do that without JS. If I need JS then I'd rather use it to set the width of the div and use ellipses.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the desired result? Should it end up looking like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8758q9uw/1/)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it should look like, but without specifying a width for the second column. The second column needs to expand to fit the width of the table, which will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using display:flex and flex:1(flex-grow:1)

check this snippet

```css
#wrapper {

  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#wrapper table {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
 
}

#table-two div {
 word-wrap:break-all;
}

.td_col_two {
  width: 100%;
}

.col_one_div {
  background: red;
}

.col_two_div {
  background: lightblue;


}

.col_three_div {
  width: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="table-one">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col_one_div">
          Robin
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td_col_two">
        <div class="col_two_div">
          Short works
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="col_three_div">
          x
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>


  <table id="table-two">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col_one_div">
          Robin
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td_col_two">
        <div class="col_two_div">
          White-space normal also works.
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="col_three_div">
          x
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

  <table id="table-three">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col_one_div">
          Robin
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td_col_two">
        <div class="col_two_div">
          nowrap does not work for long text.
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="col_three_div">
          x
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but the middle column of the last table is still too wide. If the text can't fit inside the column then it needs to be shortened. The width of the table must stay within its parent's constraints.

Comment: so you mean if the text is wide than the column width it should wrap but the middle column should expand to fit the table?

Comment: modified the code just check now is this what you want

Comment: Each row should only be a single line tall. The last table here is how it should look, but without the middle column having a specific width : https://jsfiddle.net/o044tq53/5/

Comment: if the middile column is wide ,should it wrap?

Comment: Can you please be clear of how exactly you want it...if any column is wide enough should it wrap or not?

Comment: It's best to look at how the last table looks in the jsfiddle. It needs to look exactly like that, but without the width of the middle column being specified.